# Facebook website app infinite redirects

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have one website app in facebook. It was working fine till now. But suddenly i am seeing infinite redirects.

The url looks like this after authentication.

> url.com?state=blabla&code=blabla

But it keeps redirecting. It is because I have given redirection if the authentication if false.

But I don't know why it is not successful. It was working good before few mins too.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

is always **0**

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true
));
```

version is 3.1.1

Comment: You need to provide details, your question is unanswerable as it is.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what's wrong if you don't show any code or tells us if anything changed between the time it was fine and the time you started seeing the redirects. Did you change anything in this time?

Comment: I just tried to add me few more details. I dont know the real problem since it is not working suddenly. I didnt make any change in any files...

Comment: What p3p headers do you have set?

Comment: Check if cookies are enabled Or try using cookie => false in your code.